# Wrapping PHP and HTML in PHP function to create a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode for use in WordPress, that will allow me to use PHP and HTML functionality.

I have created the shortcode and it works using simple echo Hello World, but when I try to use it to display the results of 160 lines of PHP and HTML it simply shows nothing, not even errors.

After trying several different ways, the most simple way seemed to be:

```
function imported_table( $atts ) {
    $var = file_get_contents(TEMPLATE_DIR . "/imported_table.php");
}
add_shortcode( 'imported_output', 'imported_table');
```

...where the imported_table.phpcontains my 160 lines of HTML and PHP.  The TEMPLATE_DIR is set in wp-config and works as it should - I get no 'missing file' erros, at least (after a couple of missteps).

The imported_table.php file is a little lengthy to post here but essentially it's like this:

```
<Some HTML>
<?php 
?>
<Some HTML with <?php >>
<?php 
?>
<closing HTML>
```

It's a lot of HTML and nested PHP.  The code does work by itself if I use it in a PHP plugin for WordPress, but the plugin has been shown to have vulnerbilities, and its own bugs, which is why I'm trying to use this code in a shortcode.

Comment: is error messaging turned on? By default, Wordpress turns that off. Also check if file_get_content is allowed on your server by php ini. Some servers disable it, since it can be a security risk. You're then better of using `curl`.

Comment: file_get_content doesn't have any entry in my PHP info... Does that mean it's disabled or should I be looking for something else?
EDIT: Switched on DEBUG and it gives no errors on that page.

Comment: The function `file_get_contents()` just fetches the content of a file. As a result you become a string without functionality. If you want your template to be executed try the wordpress function [load_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/) instead or require your template directly in your wordpress function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

Don't use TEMPLATE_DIR and file_get_contents.

```
    function imported_table( $atts ) {
        ob_start();
        include(get_template_directory() . "/imported_table.php");
        $var = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $var;
    }
```

Comment: Might help to explain why you are using ob_start() here. The OP doesn't seem to understand why this would be needed.

Comment: When using file_get_contents, you will not get a result from executed PHP code(I mean <?php ?> block in a WP shortcode. And TEMPLATE_DIR indicates TEMP directory on your server in shortcode.

Comment: This works.  Just as I'd also tried 'include' and that worked too.  However, when I used your code, it attempted to get the file from the parent theme root rather than the child theme I'm working on.  I replaced your line with 
```
include (TEMPLATE_DIR . "/imported_table.php");
```
And it works perfectly.  Any reason I shouldn't use the template_dir path I set?

Comment: @Reverend2100, this code was tested on my side. I think you need to use base path to find the correct file. Or you can use the relative path from your plugin with ```__FILE__```

Comment: If you want to allow overwriting your template by a theme or a childtheme use `locate_templete()`, which is available since WordPress version 1.5. WordPress comes with a ton of template related functions. Another useful function is `load_template()`, wich requires the template instead of loading the text content of a template.